# Covert from 16bit representation

Tags: swift, math, 16-bit

I receive 16bit data as UInt16 on Swift code.
16bit data correspond to the following decimal number

- 0x0000：-2
- 0x8000：0
- 0xFFFF：+2

How to convert 16 bit data into decimal number correspond as above on Swift?

Answer (score 1):

```
0x0000 = 0b 00000000 00000000
0x8000 = 0b 10000000 00000000
0xFFFF = 0b 11111111 11111111
```

How about this algorithm: if any bit of a byte is set, we count as 1 otherwise -1. `0x0000 = -1 + -1`, `0x8000 = 1 - 1`, `0xFFFF = 1 + 1`, `0xFF10 = 1 + 1`, `0x0080 = -1 + 1`

```
func getNumber(_ val: UInt16) -> Int {
  var result = (val | 0xff > 0xff) ? 1 : -1 // check left byte
  result += (val | 0xff00 > 0xff00) ? 1 : -1 // check right byte
  return result
}

print(getNumber(0x0000))
print(getNumber(0x8000))
print(getNumber(0xFFFF))
```

PS:
This webpage is a good tool as bit-manipulation visualizing. `https://bitwisecmd.com`